Does setting a default value for Alter Table in Postgres make the query significantly slower?
We had an incident very recently that caused our service to be unavailable for some minutes.
Here is the liquibase script that led to the incident:
<addColumn tableName="registration">
    <column name="retry_at" value="null" type="DATETIME"/>
    <column name="retry_counter" value="null" type="BIGINT"/>
</addColumn>


As you can see, the changeset took quite a lot of time. Our team has concluded that the default value set to null is the one to blame here. However, it somehow doesn't sit right with me.
When I check the Postgres pages 1 and 2, I see that setting the values to null is no different than removing the default value altogether. So, I don't see why this default value setting would cause such problems. On a side note, there were 12 million rows in the table.
As in the title, my question is, does setting a default value cause such downtimes?
The application startup:
Started ApplicationKt in 289.989 seconds (process running for 290.727)

Some logs before the liquibase operation:




This liquibase change was the only thing that ran before the application startup so we're pretty sure this is the cause. Without this particular change, the application startup went just fine. But still I added the application startup log here.

The team suggests that, setting a default value causes all rows to be updated however the pages I shared above states the otherwise. When it's a constant value it shouldn't update all the values instantly. Also when you don't specify a default value, there STILL is a default value (which is null, also stated in the links I shared)

Unfortunately, we don't have access to the prod environment, as developers. Moreover, it's forbidden to make direct changes on the database. The only thing we have are the logs above, and I shared some more now.

I found the root cause and it's indeed related to the value attribute in the liquibase statement.

For example, with a Change Type like addColumn, setting the defaultValue attribute on a column specifies its default value. Setting the value attribute sets all rows existing to the specified value (such a string) without modifying the column default.

The above excerpt is taken from the link below:
https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/nested-tags/column.html
So it seems like, we should have used defaultValue instead of value in the liquibase, or simply put nothing in there since the default is already null.
